# How do I navigate to a web url from Uno?

Tags: uno-platform

I have a MenuFlyoutItem that calls a command.  From the OnCommand method I would like to open a browser window based on a provided URL.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

No answer.  There doesn't seem to be a away to do it in UNO WASM. It seems that the only way to navigate out of a WASM app is to have a hyperlink button and require that the user click on it.